# How to init Vuejs + VueRouter on certain pages within Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-router

To explain it better I am creating an app with Laravel back-end (for learning purposes) and I am trying too hook lots of stuff. But I want to create only one or two of the pages to run the vue/vue-router to display certain components. Like multi-page website with few single-page apps within it.

I cut it rough

```
<div id="{{ (Route::current()->getName() == 'vue-page1') ? 'app' : '' }}">
    @yield('content')
</div>
```

but this is no solution I tried to limit the pages after that with JS using

```
if (!document.getElementById("app"))
```

doesn't get it, Vue is still initiated. I want to keep the current structure, just to stop it from initialization on pages where it shouldn't.

Comment: post the part of the `app.js` file where you are loading the content. If it is as the default one you should look at `bootstrap.js` file and make the changes there and register vue and vue-router in the if you are using.

Comment: try to load the vue router only when it is nessesry like when this `document.getElementById("app")` is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code that you posted try to build the options object beforehand than to pass it to the `new Vue` instance. Like that:

```
let options = {
    el: '#app',
    name: 'app',
    render: app => app(App),
    data: {
        a: 1
    },
    created: function () {
        // `this` points to the vm instance
        console.log('a is: ' + this.a)
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log('done');
      auth.check()
    }
}
if(document.getElementById("app-with-routes"))//yaah we have app with routes
{
    window.VueRouter = require('vue-router');
    let router = new VueRouter({
        routes: [
            {
                path: '/',
                name: 'home',
                component: Vue.component('home', require('./components/Home.vue'))
            },
            // .... all the routes you need
            ]});
    options['router'] = router
}

const app = new Vue(options);
```

That way you will be able to use all vue sweet parts without having to deal with the router.

Comment: Great, I just moved the `const app = new Vue(options);` inside the `if`

Comment: @Developer in my answer I moved most of the things inside the if because you may want to use some of the vue sweets for other pages. For example `v-if v-else` to show/hide element based on an property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including your vue.js only in pages that you need to?

```
@section('styles')
{{ (Route::current()->getName() == 'vue-page1') ? '<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>' : '' }}
@endsection
```

Comment: Webpack is in action so this is not an option as well. I am trying to keep the current structure and work it out within js or Vue